# Java HTML parsing (links)

Tags: java, html, web, jsoup

I am trying to parse a web site and get some content from it, but I am completely lost now, I am trying to get all the links from the `<div class="block block--archive">`  there is `<a class="block_link" hrek = "/curator/christoffer-rostlund-jonsson/"` I want to get these links, I have searched a lot for some guides about it, but could not find any specific answer. I have tried something but I know its in really stupid way and doesnt work:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://curatorsofsweden.com/archive/").get();
      Elements articles = doc.select("body");
       Elements element2= articles.select("div");
        Elements element3 = element2.select("article");
        Elements element4 = element3.select("div");
        System.out.println(element4.toString());
        }
```

And here is the structure of the web site that I want to get the links from:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because the website uses javascript to load the content you want. Jsoup cannot execute javascript, it's just an HTML parser. To verify that, you can get the HTML from JSOUP and save it as a file:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://curatorsofsweden.com/archive/").get();
Files.write(Paths.get("./website.html"), doc.html().getBytes());
```

The content you are looking for is not there.

You can try [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). The library uses a real browser and will execute javascript. This example prints the links you were looking for:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://curatorsofsweden.com/archive/");

By linkSelector = By.cssSelector("div[class='block block--archive'] a");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(linkSelector));

List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(linkSelector);
for (WebElement linkElement : linkElements) {
    String link = linkElement.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println("LINK " + link);
}
driver.quit();
```

Comment: I am trying it now , will answer in 5 minutes , thank you :)

Comment: for this line gives me cannot resolve method ://       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(linkSelector));

Comment: You are welcome. Here is a complete gist with imports: https://gist.github.com/squallified/bbd39ee12c10b592c840